# Learning parsing with C++

Tags: c++, parsing

I want to learn the basics of Parsing with C++.

For that matter I thought of a simple Configuration Language that might look like this:

```
/*
    same comment syntax as in C++

    keywords:
        "section" = begins a new section block
        "var"     = defines a new var
        ...
*/
section MySection {  // also valid: section "MySection" { ... }
    var someVar = "foo";
    section stuff {
        var things = "data";
    };
};
```

Dummy grammar:

```
"section" <section_name> "{" <block> "}" ";"
"var" <name> "=" <value> ";"
```

Now I wonder where I would find a beginners tutorial that might cover this Project?

Comment: Related:  There are a lot of good resources in reply to [Learning to write a compiler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669/learning-to-write-a-compiler).  While you may not be writing a compiler, the best descriptions of parsing are often found in compiler texts.

Comment: @James McNellis: Good Idea. you might want to write that as an answer, so I can accept it ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wikipedia entry on [recursive descent parsers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser) should get you started.

Comment: The Example program on TOW is pretty straightforwarded, though not exactly what i'm looking for... but still +1 for the link